# Evaluating Polynomial coefficients

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I'm trying to write a function that takes as input a list of coefficients (a0, a1, a2, a3.....a n) of a polynomial p(x) and the value x. The function will return p(x), which is the value of the polynomial when evaluated at x.

A polynomial of degree n with coefficient a0, a1, a2, a3........an is the function

```
p(x)= a0+a1*x+a2*x^2+a3*x^3+.....+an*x^n
```

So I'm not sure how to attack the problem. I'm thinking that I will need a range but how can I make it so that it can handle any numerical input for x? I'm not expecting you guys to give the answer, I'm just in need of a little kick start. Do I need a for loop, while loop or could recursive be an option here?

```
def poly(lst, x)
```

I need to iterate over the items in the list, do I use the indices for that, but how can I make it iterate over an unknown number of items?

I'm thinking I can use recursion here:

```
    def poly(lst, x):
        n = len(lst)
        If n==4:
           return lst[o]+lst[1]*x+lst[2]*x**2+lst[3]*x**3
        elif n==3:
           return lst[o]+lst[1]*x+lst[2]*x**2
        elif n==2:
           return lst[o]+lst[1]*x
        elif n==1:
           return lst[o]
        else:
            return lst[o]+lst[1]*x+lst[2]*x**2+lst[3]*x**3+lst[n]*x**n
```

This works for n<=4 but I get a index error: list index out of range for n>4, can't see why though.

Comment: Hint: look up what `sum` and `enumerate` do.  (PS: Don't forget that in Python, we use `**` and not `^` for exponentiation, i.e. `x*x = x**2`.)

Comment: I know what sum does, but what throws me off is how to write the code so that the n value is incorporated

Comment: @Snarre Check out my answer, I think that is what you wanted.

Comment: `enumerate` is there for you. Look up what it does. It should help you in creating the n for each coefficient.

Comment: @Answerers: Since OP asks for *any numerical input* depending on `x` and the coefficients one might want to use an adjusted ordering when doing the sum to avoid loosing too much precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple:

```
def poly(lst, x): 
  n, tmp = 0, 0
  for a in lst:
    tmp = tmp + (a * (x**n))
    n += 1

  return tmp

print poly([1,2,3], 2)
```

simple recursion:

```
def poly(lst, x, i = 0):
  try:
    tmp = lst.pop(0)
  except IndexError:
    return 0
  return tmp * (x ** (i)) + poly(lst, x, i+1)

print poly([1,2,3], 2)
```

Comment: Using enumerate is much easier than keeping an index i.

Comment: @Imagine yeah, looks like. Didn't know about it.

Comment: @Snarre lst.pop(0) is your "a0", first element in list

Comment: @Snarre yeah, don't need it, x**0 is 1

Comment: @Snarre you don't need recursion here. And this isn't one.

Comment: @Snarre added example with recursion.

Comment: Ok so I wrote a recursion alternative (added) it works partially, I'm getting an index error when n>4... Can't see why though

Comment: @Snarre is that trolling kung-fu ?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with what that means - I'm Swedish, sorry

Comment: Ok, no it's really not, but I've been trying to execute your simple version above and I get an error message complaining about line 4:

Comment: @Snarre yeah, tmp must be defined before trying to get something from it. fixed.

Answer (score 9):

The most efficient way is to evaluate the polynomial backwards using Horner's Rule.  Very easy to do in Python:

```
# Evaluate a polynomial in reverse order using Horner's Rule,
# for example: a3*x^3+a2*x^2+a1*x+a0 = ((a3*x+a2)x+a1)x+a0
def poly(lst, x):
    total = 0
    for a in reversed(lst):
        total = total*x+a
    return total
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def evalPoly(lst, x):
    total = 0
    for power, coeff in enumerate(lst): # starts at 0 by default
        total += (x**power) * coeff
    return total
```

Alternatively, you can use a list and then use `sum`:

```
def evalPoly(lst, x):
        total = []
        for power, coeff in enumerate(lst):
            total.append((x**power) * coeff)
        return sum(total)
```

Without enumerate:

```
def evalPoly(lst, x):
    total, power = 0, 0
    for coeff in lst:
        total += (x**power) * coeff
        power += 1
    return total
```

Alternative to non-enumerate method:

```
def evalPoly(lst, x):
    total = 0
    for power in range(len(lst)):
        total += (x**power) * lst[power] # lst[power] is the coefficient
    return total
```

Also @DSM stated, you can put this together in a single line:

```
def evalPoly(lst, x):
    return sum((x**power) * coeff for power, coeff in enumerate(lst))
```

Or, using [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=lambda#lambda):

```
evalPoly = lambda lst, x: sum((x**power) * coeff for power, coeff in enumerate(lst))
```

Recursive solution:

```
def evalPoly(lst, x, power = 0):
    if power == len(lst): return (x**power) * lst[power]
    return ((x**power) * lst[power]) + evalPoly(lst, x, power + 1)
```

`enumerate(iterable, start)` is a generator expression (so it uses `yield` instead of `return` that yields a number and then an element of the iterable. The number is equivalent to the index of the element + start.

[From the Python docs, it is also the same as](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate):

```
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

Comment: Yeah it works but we haven't covered enumerate in class so I'm not sure why or how it works.

Comment: (1) I don't think you want to start at 1.  The OP's first term is `a0*x**0`.  (2) We could compress the entire thing to `sum(coeff*x**i for i, coeff in enumerate(lst))`.

Comment: @DSM I was thinking of putting it as a one-liner, but thought that might be confusing. But I'll add it in anyway :).

Comment: Well since we haven't used enumerate or lambda in class yet I think I need to stick with indices. But what confuses me is where is the function p(x)= a0+a1*x+a2*x^2+a3*x^3+.....+an*x^n in your code guys?

Comment: @Snarre That comes from the `for` loop. `for power, coeff in enumerate(lst)` would start off with 0, a0. Then, the next would be 1, a1. a0 and a1 are the coefficients provided in `lst`, and 0 and 1 are the powers provided by the `enumerate` function.

Comment: @Snarre Check out my new edit. `for coeff in lst` provides the coefficient from the list (which is given by the user) and `power` is just a variable that you increment.

Comment: not necessarily recursive; it's more brute-force. It's not the best way, because you don't know how many exponents are going to be in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Either with recursion, or without, the essence of the solution is to create a loop on "n", because the polynomial starts at x^0 and goes up to a_n.x^n and that's the variable you should also consider as an input. Besides that, use a trick called multiply and accumulate to be able to calculate partial results on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
def evalPoly(lst, x, power):
    if power == 0:
        return lst[power]
    return ((x**power) * lst[power]) + evalPoly(lst, x, power - 1)

lst = [7, 1, 2, 3]
x = 5
print(evalPoly(lst, x, 3))
```

Equation to evaluate is - 3x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 7
when x = 5, result is - 437