# How to evaluate polynomial coefficients for animation channel spline?

Tags: python, animation, reverse-engineering, spline, polynomials

I am reverse engineering a video games animation files and have run into a brick wall. The animation sets are structured as follows:

For each animation set:

- Animation Set Name: Attack
- Number of Bones: 22
- Duration: 1.03333

and subsequently for each bone in the set:

- Bone Name: Pelvis
- Bone ID: 0
- Key Interval: 0.0333333
- Keys: 31

and then the following data is broken up into 7 channels (`Position[x,y,z]` and `Rotation quaternion[x,y,z,w]`):

Position[x,y,z] are either Constant or Original Values and I have no trouble here.

But the Rotation quaternion[x,y,z,w] channels are interpreted as Splines with N Segments and N Coefficients and I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how I would evaluate the Splines into data I can punch into a 3D program.

I know that each channel's spline is plotted as Y and X would equal normalized time (0 to 1).

This Q+A ( [Evaluating Polynomial coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927229/evaluating-polynomial-coefficients) ) seems to be what I need:

A polynomial of degree n with coefficient a0, a1, a2, a3........an is the function

p(x)= a0+a1*x+a2*x^2+a3*x^3+.....+an*x^n

and written as Python code:

```
def poly(lst, x): 
  n, tmp = 0, 0
  for a in lst:
    tmp = tmp + (a * (x**n))
    n += 1

  return tmp
```

But I'm not sure I'm doing it right when i put `lst` as the coefficients for each segment and `x = Duration / Keys`.

Here is the first animation set's 'Rot.x' channel and its Segments and Coefficients:

Segments = 3

Segment 1

- Coeff1: 0.0198117
- Coeff2: 0.00826611
- Coeff3: 0.0521381
- Coeff4: -0.00210184

Segment 2

- Coeff1: -0.181324
- Coeff2: 1.09073
- Coeff3: -1.77627
- Coeff4: 0.920407

Segment 3

- Coeff1: -0.0335189
- Coeff2: 0.265863
- Coeff3: -0.359457
- Coeff4: 0.147228

The way I'm looking at this is each segment is 1/3 of the duration (1.03333) and furthermore each segments coefficients are to be evaluated over 1/3 of the number of keys (31), but the output using the above `poly(lst, x)` function for

- segment 1 = from 0.019 to 4.90 to -7.15
- segment 2 = from -0.18 to 20985.41
- segment 3 = from -0.03 to 3296.11

Obviously I'm doing something wrong since the output is way too high.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any data for the other quaternion components (y, z, w)?

Comment: Also, I don't really see the problem you're experiencing.  [The plot looks fine to me](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7B0.0198117+%2B+0.00826611+x+%2B+0.0521381+x%5E2+-+0.00210184+x%5E3%2C+-0.181324+%2B+1.09073+x+-+1.77627+x%5E2+%2B+++++0.920407+x%5E3%2C+-0.0335189+%2B+0.265863+x+-+0.359457+x%5E2+%2B+0.147228+x%5E3%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+1.0333%7D%5D).  I don't think the segments are divided evenly into thirds, however.