# How does enumerate work in polynomial function (Python)?

Tags: python, enumeration

I am a Python beginner and a bit confused about enumerate function in summing the polynomial problem in the following SO thread:

[Evaluating Polynomial coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927229/evaluating-polynomial-coefficients)

The thread includes several ways to solve the summing of polynomials. I understand the following version well:

```
def evalP(lst, x):
    total = 0
    for power in range(len(lst)):
        total += (x**power) * lst[power] # lst[power] is the coefficient
    return total
```

E.g. if I take third degree polynomial with x = 2, the program returns 15 as I expected based on pen and paper calculations:

```
evalP([1,1,1,1],2)

Out[64]:
15
```

But there is another, neater version of doing this that uses enumerate function:

```
evalPoly = lambda lst, x: sum((x**power) * coeff for power, coeff in enumerate(lst))
```

The problem is that I just can't get that previous result replicated with that. This is what I've tried:

```
coeff = 1
power = 3
lst = (power,coeff)
x = 2
evalPoly(lst,x)
```

And this is what the program returns:

```
Out[68]:
5
```

Not what I expected. I think I have misunderstood how that enumerate version takes on the coefficient. Could anyone tell me how I am thinking this wrong?

The previous version seems more general as it allows for differing coefficients in the list, whereas I am not sure what that scalar in enumerate version represents.

Comment: I don't understand why you're passing different arguments to `evalPoly`. If you pass `[1,1,1,1],2` as you did for `evalP`, you get the right answer again: 15.

Comment: Thanks! I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `evalPoly` with the same arguments as `evalP`, e.g. `evalPoly([1,1,1,1],2)`

When you call `evalPoly([3,1],2)`, it return 3*2^0 + 1*2^1 which equals 5.